# can anyone tell me whats the use of having digestor-rules.xml

Tags: java, apache-commons-digester

I know it is used for parsing xml data and converting them into objects.Does that make any sense in using this in an enterprise application. Please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commons Digester is a bit old-fashioned, but it still has its uses.

In cases where you have large streams of XML, it can be impractical to read it all into a binding framework like JAXB, due to memory constraints. Commons Digester allows you to build objects from the XML stream on the fly.  Note, however, that JAXB also has some support for XML streaming (see [here](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/guide/Dealing_with_large_documents.html)), and while it's not ultimately as flexible as Commons Digester, it's probably going to be easier to live with.

Comment: thanks skaffman for you quick reply. Thats means I can use rules xml in my enterprise app.Please do let me know if you have any additional thoughts.